# How to trim dates which is in VARCHAR2

Tags: plsql

I have a varchar2 field in this format "Tue Aug 03 10:14:14 PDT 2021" I want to convert this into
MM-DD-YYYY format, how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```sql
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('Tue Aug 03 10:14:14 PDT 2021', 'FXDY MON DD HH:MI:SS "PDT" YYYY'), 'MM-DD-YYYY') from  dual;
```

Please also note that it explicitly (FX) expects `PDT` as timezone.